# Do gnomes kill other gnomes? If so, how?

Tags: gnomoria

I ran across a strange situation.  I was looking at a gnome who had not been very helpful in a recent combat, and realized that there was a Kill entry for a gnome in his list.  How did my one gnome kill my other gnome?

Maybe I need to create a focus group to train these fighters that there is good touch and bad touch, and killing your buddy is very bad touch!!   :P

But really, I can't figure out how this happened given these two screens:

First, I saw that in the history, he had bled to death.  Not a very unique situation for the difficulty I am playing at.

[image: Dead gnomes tell no tales?]

But then in my Current Nurse's Kill list...

[image: Vinno, was a fine chap...]

At least he was notable?!?   I did not know this was possible.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: Did you look through the combat log? Should be noted there who actually attacked Vinno. The kills are sometimes a bit buggy so investigating this could help. Alternatively, upload your save game to e.g. Google Drive or Dropbox and share it, so people can have a look.

Comment: The combat log had no record of this fight, looking from inside Gnomoria.  I hope I did not accidentally delete the combat log.  It looks like I am missing everything for the summer of year one, which would be 2 combat events.  Is there another log file I can look at, maybe?  I suspect I hit the clear button and I am a little disappointed in myself.

Comment: Could they have been sparring and Vinno got wounded?

Comment: I remember the battle, it was the 3rd day of summer, because the kingdom was 1d 21h away, and the night shift at the practice range was not yet set up.  So the fighting started on the 3rd.  This was the first battle, so I was a little zealous and sent everybody in.  My settings are 2x enemy strength, and 2x enemy frequency.  So I knew it was going to be a tough fight for the new guys.  Four gnomes bled out, because I did not catch that my nurse/tailor was one of the injured.  I remember the battle, but nothing is in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forums.gnomoria.com/index.php?topic=5214.0), there is three possible case.

1. Your gnome was injured while training and bleed to death, or push the other in a river!
2. One of your gnomes turned into a zombie and killed Vinno. Zombies keep their original name.
3. There could be a very rare accident where, in a fight, a gnome misses and hit another gnome.

From what you describe, looks like situation 1 and 2 can be excluded. So, maybe your gnome was killed by a friendly hit, but we will probably never know as the dev vanished and looks like your combat logs got deleted. This could still be a bug tho.